# Is there a way to send mail when SQL Server database structure has changed? 

Tags: sql-server, email, triggers

Is there a way to know when the database is changed and get mail notification on it.

How could it be done on SQL Server?

Note: I rather not use Exchange mail.

update:
looking throw msdn guides , they seem irelevent since there is not such thing as "databse mail"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175951%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: What type of change?  table, procedure, permissions, data?

Comment: table or procedure or view. not data.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'not such thing as "database mail"'? Is it disabled in your SQL server environment, or are you using SQL 2000 (or some other pre-SQL 2005 version)?

Comment: after your edit: are you saying that Database Mail is not configured/installed or that it will not be?  Appears to me there are two legs to you question: 1) how to identify 2) how to send.  I'll let you worry about 2 since I'm unsure after your update but #1) see [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx)  You could create a trigger off that table OR Write a job/agent which runs X often looking at things that have changed since the time your coded into the job/query.

Comment: @xQbert - `sys.objects` is a view not a table and you can't create triggers on system objects anyway. Not that you need to because SQL Server has DDL triggers for this requirement.

Comment: Martin's right (no surprise:D) it is a view and he's also right that it is a DDL trigger not just "A trigger off that table". and that you can't create triggers on system objects. But to actually offer a pointer for the OP... look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989.aspx) What you appear to be attempting to do is "AUDIT" DDL changes to your database"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which aspect of the database would you like to monitor? Objects like tables added or droppen, dabase settings changed?

You could use a database level DDL trigger (SQL Server 2005 and newer) and watch for events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989.aspx